# Why is this mathematical JOIN not working on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, math, join

So, yesterday I noticed you can put a kind of an "offset" to a join in SQL, when I tried

"JOIN logs2 ON l1.LogNumber = l2.LogNumber -3"

Where it would join for example LogNumber 1 from the first table to the LogNumber 4 in the second. And this works perfectly. My problem is though, when I tried to make a more complicated "mathematical join", and I don't seem to know how to get it to work. My problem is as following: I now have a table with some measurement data from logs, as in wood. There's another table which has data from the boards which have been sawn from said log. Four boards are from the one same log. I'm trying to make a join where the first four boards in the table are joined to the first log, the second batch of four boards to the second, et cetera. The BoardNumber in the second table doesn't start from 1 though, but from 230609. So, I did a little math and found out how you can calculate the correct log and boardnumber, and I tried the following code:

"JOIN boards pg ON ((p1.LogNumber - 0,75) * 4 + 230608) = BoardNumber"

This alone should join only the first board from every log, so I'd have to make more joins to get the other ones as well. However, this doesn't work, and I get the error 1241 "Operand should contain 1 columns". When I changed the parentheses a bit, it says "1241: Operand should contain 2 columns". And I really don't understand what's wrong with this JOIN.

Comment: Obvious error - a comma instead of a dot as decimal separator. For more detailed diagnostic you must provide complete query text.

Comment: Joining condition can be an expression of any complexity level which produces scalar result. Even a subquery - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f44297edcd545b82b3a026b234651cd

Answer (score 1):

If by `0,75` you mean three-quarters, then you need to write `0.75` instead; see [§9.1.2 "Numeric Literals" in the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html).

However, I'd actually recommend sticking with integers and writing `((p1.LogNumber * 4 - 3) + 230608)` instead, to avoid the risk of rounding errors and so on.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot, that's a bit silly of me. In my country/language we always use the comma as decimal separator so it looked perfectly normal to me, but I should've known.